# Merging 2 lists and remove double entries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code that loads up 2 lists with this code:

```
with open('blacklists.bls', 'r') as f:
            L = [dnsbls.strip() for dnsbls in f]
with open('ignore.bls', 'r') as f2:
            L2 = [ignbls.stip() for ignbls in f2]
```

dnsbls contains:

```
list1
list2
list3
```

ignbls contains

```
list2
```

What I want to do is merge dnsbls and ignbls and then remove any lines that appears more than once and print those with "for". I was thinking something like:

```
for combinedlist in L3:
            print combinedlist
```

Which in the aboe example would print out:

```
list1
list3
```

Comment: I tried writing the content of dnsbls and ignbls to a file, say list.temp and then opened that file. Got stuck figuring out how to remove every line that appears more than once.

Comment: the order is irrelevant for the current project, so no need to think about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of lists:

```
L3 = list(set(L).difference(L2))
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> L=['list1','list2','list3']
>>> L2=['list2']
>>> set(L).difference(L2)
set(['list1', 'list3'])
>>> list(set(L).difference(L2))
['list1', 'list3']
```

For your purposes you probably don't have to convert it back to a list again, you can iterate over the resulting set just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If ignores are smaller than the blacklists (which is normally the case I think), then (untested):

```
with open('blacklists.bls') as bl, open('ignore.bls') as ig:
    bl_for = (line.strip() for line in bl if 'for' not in line)
    ig_for = (line.strip() for line in ig if 'for' not in line)
    res = set(ig_for).difference(bl_for)
```